# Persist checkbox state till monday

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm needing a "to do list" that will reset every Monday. So users can check off their list but then on Monday all the check boxes are unchecked.

thanks!!

I've found this helpful.
https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-persist-checkbox-checked-state-after-page-reload/#demo

This has all the code, it just doesn't have a way to reset all the boxes on Monday.

Here is the JS

```
var formValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formValues')) || {};
var $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");
var $button = $("#checkbox-container button");

function allChecked(){
  return $checkboxes.length === $checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
}

function updateButtonStatus(){
  $button.text(allChecked()? "Uncheck all" : "Check all");
}

function handleButtonClick(){
  $checkboxes.prop("checked", allChecked()? false : true)
}

function updateStorage(){
  $checkboxes.each(function(){
    formValues[this.id] = this.checked;
  });

  formValues["buttonText"] = $button.text();
  localStorage.setItem("formValues", JSON.stringify(formValues));
}

$button.on("click", function() {
  handleButtonClick();
  updateButtonStatus();
  updateStorage();
});

$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
  updateButtonStatus();
  updateStorage();
});

// On page load
$.each(formValues, function(key, value) {
  $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
});

$button.text(formValues["buttonText"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

the toDoList array is initialized based on the checkboxes and their completion statuses stored in formValues. The checkMonday function checks if today is Monday and resets the completion statuses if it is. The rest of the code is mostly the same as in the original implementation, with some modifications to use toDoList instead of formValues.

```
var formValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formValues')) || {};
var $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");
var $button = $("#checkbox-container button");

// Initialize the list items and their completion statuses
var toDoList = [];
$checkboxes.each(function(){
  toDoList.push({ item: $(this).next().text(), completed: formValues[this.id] });
});

function allChecked(){
  return $checkboxes.length === $checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
}

function updateButtonStatus(){
  $button.text(allChecked()? "Uncheck all" : "Check all");
}

function handleButtonClick(){
  $checkboxes.prop("checked", allChecked()? false : true)
}

function updateStorage(){
  $checkboxes.each(function(){
    formValues[this.id] = this.checked;
  });

  formValues["buttonText"] = $button.text();
  localStorage.setItem("formValues", JSON.stringify(formValues));
}

// Check if today is Monday and reset the list if it is
function checkMonday() {
  let today = new Date();
  if (today.getDay() === 1) {
    toDoList.forEach(item => {
      item.completed = false;
    });
    $checkboxes.prop("checked", false);
    updateStorage();
  }
}

$button.on("click", function() {
  handleButtonClick();
  updateButtonStatus();
  updateStorage();
});

$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
  updateButtonStatus();
  updateStorage();
});

// On page load, display the list items and check if it's Monday
$.each(toDoList, function(index, item) {
  $("#" + $checkboxes[index].id).prop('checked', item.completed);
});
updateButtonStatus();
checkMonday();

// Set up an interval to check for Monday every minute
setInterval(() => {
  checkMonday();
}, 60 * 1000);
```

Hope it helps